# Icon section not loading? Sitecore 8.2U7

Tags: sitecore-client

The Icon window for changing icon is not loading. It has some script issue.

[image]

Comment: I encountered this issue sometime back when that version was first released. The fastest way to get this working is to copy the previous version of jQuery to that file name.

Comment: Just to avoid this issue I suggest using [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks). For instance, Sitecore Rocks loads icons collection faster than standard Sitecore approach.

Comment: Replacing jQueryUI with v1.11.4 fixed the selector issue, but view is completely blocked by an overlay.

https://photoland.io/i/26H8xl

Comment: @KumarDeepak Were you able to find a proper solution for this issue?

Comment: @SurbhiKochhar: Try jquery UI v1.11.4. Are you seeing a console error?

Comment: @KumarDeepak Yes it's the exact same issue but we won't be able to add older jQuery version in the env. So looking for a fix other than that.